QR disc SP-PD8 dynamo hub connector creeping round with wheel rotation
I have an SP-PD8 dynamo hub on the front of my tourer, powering an Axa Luxx 70 front and unbranded rear light for 3W nominal. Whenever I put the wheel in, I orient the connector down and back  -- 7 or 8 o'clock looking from the right hand side.  After a front wheel puncture I did this, and within 20km it was pointing up and forwards (2 o'clock).  I opened the (external cam) QR, rotated the hub/connector, and closed the QR tighter.  It's as tight as I can reasonably press with the heel of my hand and I might need a cheater bar to open it again*.  The connector has rotated again.
This happened before, to the extent that I snapped the dynamo wires on a ride (luckily I had backup lights, but not good ones and not fully charged).  Then I fixed it by doing up the QR tighter, but it's already tighter than reasonable.  It feels like a hub issue rather than a QR issue.
How I set it up:

How it soon ends up

The hub was serviced last year and runs nicely (and this is no longer my big miles bike).  I'm extremely wary of trying to attach something to hold the connector body in place.  The failure modes could easily be painful and the connector isn't shaped well for just putting a thin cable tie round it.

* The mudguard stays get in the way slightly, but finding something to press against is more of an issue.  The amount I have to pull to open it feels like lifting about 40kg with 2 fingers.

I should have a picture, but I should have checked it had actually taken before walking away from the bike this morning

Disk or rim brake?

@DanGao good point. Disc. And I've got the bike here to take a photo

The hub has never had an anti rotate washer previously?

How big is the electrical load on it?

What type of skewer are you using?

Do you have those stupid forward facing fork ends?

Please add the relevant details to your question.

Are you sure the bearings are good?

@Noise I've added the electrical load and skewer. I'd already said the hub runs nicely - so the bearings are good. As for the fork ends, they're fairly visible in the photos, but I wonder if you mean something specific because I'm more used to forward facing dropouts than anything else and I'm not sure what would make some stupid

Chris, try a Shimano or Mavic skewer to start. External cam is only suitable for disc when brand new and sometimes not even then. Your electrical load sounds fine -- everything works as expected, not too bright or too dim? Your dropouts look like they face flat forwards instead of down which increases the chance of wheel creep when there is another problem. I used to think they were cool but have come to the conclusion they are unnecessary and somewhat irritating, even on a nice bike.

@Noise this is the skewer that came with the hub, but I might switch to a security one. These dropouts are between forwards and down. Old-fashioned steel forks but a nice ride

SP don't supply a skewer with the hub (in the last 4 years at least) so it is supplied by your wheel builder and might be rubbish.

Meaning it is a suspect component that can't be compared against other SP hubs in the wild.

The pinhead skewer won't give better hold and is easy to remove (i.e. not very secure) so you should try a proper quality branded skewer as a control before continuing.

@noise pinhead tightens with a tool not a cam, so can be tighter. As for security, QR is as bad as possible, even track nuts deter theft and pinhead is better than those. In practice it's enough that I've never lost a front wheel with one as its only lock - and I'm currently using a cable for the front wheel which is probably worse, being defeatable with more compact tools

... The wheel builder is me, so if it's not an SP skewer it must be one that came with the joytech original hub. Anyway I need to replace it having bent the handle getting it off. But I couldn't find my front pinhead in the toolbox while I was away.

I'm suggesting that you, Chris, with your background in science and optical tech, eliminate the weakest variable with a known good, high quality skewer. The pin head skewers are not great and a shimano, mavic or campag internal cam skewer delivers alot of clamping force very easily. It is hard to judge the state of bearings in a dynamo hub too so unless you are saying they have been replaced, they are the second suspect.

@Noise I'm certainly prepared to replace the external cam skewer. But if I can't find my front pinhead I might go for a hex key one, and eliminate the cam altogether - mechanically the same as pinhead. I've swapped to shimano internal cam on my mtb because external cams loosened, but brief tests with pinhead were good on that. The skewer isn't loose here though, so even if it's at fault, the fault is different

@ChrisH, i know what you are saying chris, but even so, i implore you to try it so we can comprehensively rule it out. Use the MTB skewer and go for a ride.  Many problems are caused by these cheap skewers (eg joytech) on disc brake bikes. Pinhead fine one you have an established baseline.

@Noise the issue is it's seemingly intermittent. With the current skewer done up stupidly tight it was fine for 75km of sometimes rough roads on Sunday. The same skewer, normal tight, and it failed in 20km. So I'd have to borrow one for a while. But if I'm going to do an experiment, I'd rather use something I can do up with a torque wrench than the cam action, which isn't a measurable force

Done up stupidly tight it's reliable. I haven't had any issues since I asked the question, and while it's no longer my main bike I must have done the best part of 1000 km since then, but I haven't had to take the wheel off.  Unfortunately I can't find my Pinhead front skewer.  It must have been on the bike that got stolen.

-Idea-
I've had something like this, but it was in the rear wheel.
In my case, the rear QR was backing off no matter how tight it was, which caused the chain to pull the wheel crooked in the dropouts and bind on the frame.
The cause was a combination of a worn/cheap-soft QR nut, and a very hard/smooth dropout face.  A temporary fix was to roughen the outside of the dropout face, and to use a small triangular rattail file to re-form the ridges on the QR's nut.  Replacing the QR was needed eventually and I also dimpled the dropout-face with a punch to add texture.

However in your case, I can't see what could be adding the rotational force to move the axle in the dropout.
If the hub was exerting a significant resistance to motion, you'd feel it while riding.
Is it possible that the front disk brake is involved somehow?  When braking, the rotational force is somehow driving the hub around a small angle?   Or maybe there's a three-way triangle with the mudguard stays that allows small rotation over time?
Perhaps in the workshop, slacken the QR slightly and try a bunch of braking actions while looking closely at the axle?

I wouldn't be too confident of feeling a resistance while riding - I'm more likely to blame my body if a ride feels hard - but it spins nicely. A short test ride yesterday with the QR normal-tight was fine even under both sharp and sustained braking. I'm away but can use the rack on my van as a workstand so may test with it quite loose. I'm inclined to change the skewer anyway. I've got a pinhead security one I was thinking of fitting. I also can't find the source of rotational force. It feels like it must be that end of the hub. In that case a tight QR might increase bearing load unhelpfully
